# # pragma directive and its uses in c

Tags: c, pragma

can anyone tell my what does the #pragma can do in the c language . what are its uses and why the above program is not giving the output 'inside v1'& 'inside v2' in the following program ...

```
# include<stdio.h>
void v1();
void v2();
# pragma startup v1

# pragma exit v2

int main()
{
printf("inside main\n");
return 0;

}
void v1()
{
printf("inside v1\n");

}
void v2()
{
printf("inside v2\n");
}
```

i also want to know what a are the uses of the #pragma directive .... plz help

Comment: The functions `v1` and `v2` are not called by the `main` function, so the text they need to print will not show up.  This looks like a compiler specific issue as far as specifying startup and exit functions.  Tell us which compiler you are using and the OS (platform).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`#pragma` are compiler/vendor specific directives to the compiler. You'd have to look up the documentation for the particular compiler you're using.